# Minecraft crashes on launch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm using Minecraft release 1.15.2. When I click play in the Minecraft launcher it shows me a white screen, and a dialog comes up with the launcher crash report.

Here is the crash report :

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Oops.

Time: २१/२/२० ९:१७ अपराह्न
Description: Initializing game

r: Non [a-z0-9/._-] character in path of location: minecraft:dynamic/light_map_१
    at sm.(SourceFile:38)
    at sm.(SourceFile:43)
    at eak.a(SourceFile:119)
    at dqs.(SourceFile:35)
    at dqn.(SourceFile:150)
    at dbn.(SourceFile:492)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:166)

A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Render thread
Stacktrace:
    at sm.(SourceFile:38)
    at sm.(SourceFile:43)
    at eak.a(SourceFile:119)
    at dqs.(SourceFile:35)
    at dqn.(SourceFile:150)
    at dbn.(SourceFile:492)
```

These are my pc specs: 
Processor Core i3 2100 (2nd gen)
RAM: 4GB
Graphics card: Nividia Geforce Gt 710
Operating system: Windows 8.1

I installed Minecraft and when I tried to launch it, it didn't, and showed me the crash report.

So far I have tried these following fixes:

1. Reinstalling Minecraft.
2. Updating and reinstalling Java.
3. Updating drivers.
4. Spend hours on Youtube to find a fix.
5. I have tried other launchers too (Tlauncher, SKlauncher).
6. I have tried running in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Minecraft bug, you should post it on the [bug tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse) (you'll have to create account for that)

Meanwhile, try to change the JVM locale from the Minecraft launcher:

1. Click on 'Installations' at the top
2. Click on the the version you are playing (it will probably say 'Latest release')
3. Click on 'More options'
4. In the 'JVM Arguments' field add `-Duser.language=en-US`. Make sure you do not change the other arguments and that what you are adding is separated from them with a space.

If that does not work for some reason, check if you can [change your Windows locale](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%208%20change%20locale) to English. This may break other programs on your computer though.